# error:vlc not opening the mrl

Tags: vlc

I am performing live audio streaming from a server to a client using gstreamer.

Server is set up as RTSP server ,and client will be using VLC to receive the input stream.
Server program is sends the sound card audio to the client, . but unfortunately vlc at the client side is showing the following error

`YOUR INPUT CAN'T BE OPENED
VLC IS UNABLE TO OPEN THE PROBLEM 'RTSP://LOCALHOST:8554/SER'CHECK THE LOG FOR DETAILS`

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is? Is it something related to VLC version? I think the server is OK because it is showing messages telling it started the listening process. Please suggest me the methods to correct this error.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens you can change the RTSP to RTMP or MMS and it should work unless the link is dead

Comment: but iam supposed to use rtsp for my project as my code is based on rtsp